# Cluster_leiden(), what is / where can I find the meaning of the value $quality in the result object?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, igraph

The following code

```
library(igraph)
g <- make_ring(5)
set.seed(1)
cle <- cluster_leiden(g, resolution=1, objective_function=c("CPM", "modularity")[1])

modularity(g, membership(cle))
cle$quality

# print_all(g)    
# print.default(cle)
```

returns:

```
> modularity(g, membership(cle))
[1] -0.2
> cle$quality
[1] -0.5
```

Question:
what is / where can I find the meaning of the value $quality in the result object.
It is not the modularity...

Comment: "quality" is the objective function described in https://r.igraph.org/reference/cluster_leiden.html The modularity is a special case, which can be selected either as described in the docs or by using `objective_function='modularity'`.

Comment: Thanks. If you write an answer I can accept it. Otherwise I keep my answer. It does deserve a line in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by https://stackoverflow.com/users/695132/szabolcs the objective function equals:

```
 (1/2m) (ΣAij - Σ γ.ni.nj), whenever i and j are in the same community.
```

In this example:

- ni   evaluate to 1, as no weight is assigned to any vertex.
- m   evaluates to 5 edges.
- ΣAij evaluates to zero as all the communities are singletons without a self loop.
- γ evaluates to 1.
- Σ γ.ni.nj evaluates to 5.

Giving (0 - 5) / 10 = -0.5.